# Python Client-server problems

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, client-server

I am making a chat program.
I have a (TCP) server which creates a new thread for every connection request it gets.

1. I'm having problems when the client quits/terminates connection. The server raises an error(below). How do I handle it?
2. And, the server has to send the 'data' it receives from one client to another (changeable) client.
   How do I implement this??

I receive this error when the client quits :

```py
Exception in thread Thread-1:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python2.7 For Chintoo\lib\threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
      File "C:\Python2.7 For Chintoo\lib\threading.py", line 505, in run
        self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\karuna\Desktop\Jython\Python\My Modules\Network\Multi-server.py", line 23, in recv_loop
        data = client.recv(1024)
    error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

My scripts:

**Multi-server.py**

```py
import os, socket, time, threading, random

class Server:
    def __init__(self,host,port,user):
        self.port = port
        self.host = host
        self.user = user
        self.bufsize = 1024
        self.addr = (host,port)

        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET , socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.socket.bind(self.addr)
        print "Server running on",host,"at port",port

        self.socket.listen(5)

def recv_loop(server,client,caddr):
    print 'Connected To',caddr

    while True:
        global clients
        name = clients[client]
        data = client.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        print name + " said: " + data
    client.close()


host = 'localhost'
port = random.randint(1025,60000)
user = 'No one'

server = Server(host, port, user)

clients = {}
threads = []
while True:
    client, caddr = server.socket.accept()
    # name extraction
    name = client.recv(1024)

    clients[client] = name

    thread = threading.Thread(target=recv_loop, args=(server,client, caddr))
    thread.start()
```

**client.py**

```py
from socket import *

host = 'localhost'
name = raw_input('Enter name: ')
port = int(raw_input('Enter server port: '))
bufsiz = 1024
addr = (host, port)

tcpClient = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM)
tcpClient.connect(addr)

# sending name
tcpClient.send(name)

while True:
    data = raw_input('> ')
    if not data:
        break
    tcpClient.send(data)
raw_input('Enter to Quit')
```

Comment: Do you want to send all messages from clients to all other clients?

Comment: No, only to a specific client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem 1**

Just close the socket connection at client side:

```
raw_input('Enter to Quit')
tcpClient.close()
```

**Problem 2**

You are looking at producer consumer problem here.

Basic solution:

Receiving loop should acquire a `threading.Condition`, update a global array and call `notifyAll`. Sending loops should acquire the `condition`, read data from the array and send to client.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done socket programming in Python, but you might want to cleanly close your socket connection before the client quits.  I would use `close` method in the client.